Newsmatic - 1.3.11 There was an error in importing demo. Please reload the page and try again
I am new to WordPress, and I installed it on the server under my domain; there is a new theme called "Newsmatic - 13.11". I'm trying to import the demo of that theme, but after 50%, it's showing this error - There was an error in importing the demo. Please reload the page and try again.
It would be very helpful if anyone could guide me in fixing it.
Many thanks in advance.


Increase PHP Limits
WordPress demo imports can fail if the server's PHP settings are too restrictive. You can increase the following settings:

PHP Memory Limit: Set to at least 256M
Maximum Execution Time: Set to 300 seconds or more
Max Input Time: Set to 300 seconds
Max Upload File Size: Set to at least 64M or more
Max Post Size: Set to 64M or more

Increase PHP Limits
WordPress demo imports can fail if the server's PHP settings are too restrictive. You can increase the following settings:
If you don't have direct access to the server's php.ini, you can add the following code to your WordPress .htaccess file:
PHP Memory Limit: Set to at least 256M
Maximum Execution Time: Set to 300 seconds or more
Max Input Time: Set to 300 seconds
Max Upload File Size: Set to at least 64M or more
Max Post Size: Set to 64M or more



Thank you so much.
The demo is imported, and one more thing I need to ask.
In the domain, I am able to check the robots.txt file, but I am not able to get the file on the server. Can you please guide me from where it's coming.
